# Is it dangerous to let the user input into a LIKE sql statement

Tags: sql-injection, mysql

Assuming I want to implemante a search engine, is it dangerous to let the user into a `LIKE`. For example :

`SELECT user FROM table WHERE user LIKE "[user input]"`

In this case, I assume user will be allowed to type characters such as `%`,`_`
We also assume that we properly escape injection characters such as `"`,`'`,`

I'm thinking about possible Mysql DDOS if the database contain a large amount of user. Is there other(s) risk ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The risk is no different than accepting user input for a regular evaluation. You still need to sanitize the data as well as use safe practices such as stored procedures.

The unique issue with `LIKE` comes into play when it is used but shouldn't be. For example your application wants to retrieve something with a certain ID but using `LIKE` could return a similar but different ID. One you wouldn't returned to your end user. But this isn't an issue you should have with a search engine.

On an additional note using `LIKE` with MySQL will give you a very basic and limited search engine that doesn't scale well at all. For alternatives consider [matching against FullText searchable columns](https://www.mullie.eu/mysql-as-a-search-engine/) or using something meant for the job like Lucene, Sphinx, Elasticsearch, Solr.